# compile exception in playframework code

Tags: maven, playframework-1.x

I have recently configured an existing playframework project on my eclipse but I am getting a compile time exception classes like

import controllers.playtemplate.security.SecuredUser;

import controllers.playtemplate.security.WebsealSecure;

Can you please let me know what maven dependency would be required for this module of playframework so that i can get the code compiled?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by running the following command

play run -DrunEnv=local